# Why do we ignore parasitic capacitance in dc analysis of transistors?

Tags: voltage, transistors, capacitor, current, resistance

Consider a transistor that has parasitic capacitance of the order of pico-Farads.

> Then at low frequencies, consider 10Hz
>
> $$X_C=1/(2\pi f C)$$
>
> \$X_C\$ will be in the range of giga-ohms.

This means that the resistance of the device is so high, that it must not allow current to flow through it.

This says us that any device that has a parasitic capacitance must now allow dc through flow through it. But indeed devices with parasitic capacitances allow dc to flow through them. How is this true?

This also means that at dc, the reactance is infinity and no current must flow through the transistor, but indeed current flows the device and we do many dc analysis.

How does this become possible?

Comment: Parasitic capacitance is between two circuit nodes that we don't generally want it to be, it is not along the path that we want the current to flow.

Comment: ..."but indeed current flows"...Yes? How do you know? Did you measure it? Or do you mean switch-on transients?

Comment: Parasitic capacitance is in parallel with some resistance. Current can still flow through the latter (unless the resistance is infinite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parasitic capacitances do not allow any DC current to flow through them. These capacitances are generally in parallel (or a parallel-series combination) across a pair of terminals - for example between Source and Drain on a MOSFET.

Because they are in parallel there are two paths for the current to flow - through the parasitic element or directly through the device. At AC, some current will flow through the parasitic element, and some through the device (if the device conducts between those two terminals in the mode it is in).

At DC, no current will flow through parasitic capacitances, but some current can flow (in parallel) through the device. Again, this is only if the device conducts between those two terminals in the mode it is in.

If you post a diagram of the transistor model you are using with its parasitics labelled up I can better illustrate this for you.

Comment: Thanks buddy! You helped me a lot! But can I know why do we characterise parasitic capacitances to be in parallel with the device.

Comment: It generally works out that capacitances appear in parallel (so that a zero value results in ideal behaviour - i.e. it disappears) and inductors / resistors appear in series (for the same reason). If you had a parasitic resistance in parallel, then when it fell to zero it would actually short out two terminals, which is not ideal behaviour! If you want to know more about the individual cases, you need to study a full fields-approach model of the device in question. I'm sure there's something in Horowitz and Hill's "The Art of Electronics" on this.